# SharePoint Designer 2010 does not allow end users to make backups of their sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, backup, restore

SharePoint Designer 2010 does not allow end users to make backups of their sites, so is there any other way we can perform the backup using the same SharePoint Designer 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer you are looking for, but no.

The site is not just made up of the files you see, but also data stored in the database. The 2007 SPD backup feature was able to get that information but 2010 has no way to access it.